# How to make whole view linkable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to make the whole view linkable.

This is my rewrite rule:

```
<div class="news_column_wrapper z-depth-1 card">
<div class="news_column_images card-image">[field_images]</div>
<div class="news_column_content_wrapper">
<div class="news_column_created"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;[created]</div>
<div class="news_column_title">[title]</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my view field screenshoot, I want to make the whole box clickable:

[image]

I have tried with

```
    <div class="news_column_wrapper z-depth-1 card">
<a href="[path]">
        <div class="news_column_images card-image">[field_images]</div>
        <div class="news_column_content_wrapper">
        <div class="news_column_created"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>&nbsp;[created]</div>
        <div class="news_column_title">[title]</div>
        </div>
</a>
        </div>
```

but nothing happens. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? Does this overridden template shows bolded in _Template information_ in View (means it's loaded properly)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more an HTML issue than a Drupal one. 
The `<a>` tag is an inline tag, and you have placed `<div>` tags inside of it. The natural display of the `<a>` tag will make that, only the text will be clickable.

What you can do is use CSS to make the `<a>` a block element, therefore, making the clickable zone extend to the whole block.

First add a class to your link:

```
<a class='block_link'>
    <h2>My title</h2>
    <div>My content</div>
</a>
```

Then, in your CSS, make the `<a>` tag displaying like a block.

```
a {
  display:block;
}
```

That should do the trick.